# How to add a transition to a navbar dropdown

Tags: jquery, css

I just finished making a navbar for mobile and  would like to add a transition to it so that it drops down slower than it is currently.

Here my jquery:

```
(function( $ ){   
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $(".burguer-nav").on("click", function(){
          $("header nav ul").toggleClass("open"); 
       }); 
   });    
})(jQuery);
```

and the css:

```
span.burguer-nav {
    display: none;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 845px){
    .main-navigation li a {
        display: block;
        text-align:center;
    }
    .burguer-nav{
        display: block !important;
        height: 40px;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-size: 18pt;
    }
    header nav ul{
        overflow:hidden;
        height:0;
        background-color: #505050;
    }
    header nav ul.open{
        height:auto;
    }
}
```

How and where can I add the transition?

Comment: You can add a `transition: height` property to `header nav ul`, but only if .open's height property is an actual value. The browser won't transition to values of "auto"

Answer (score 0):

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 845px){
    .main-navigation li a {
        display: block;
        text-align:center;
    }
    .burguer-nav{
        display: block !important;
        height: 40px;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-size: 18pt;
    }
    header nav ul{
        overflow:hidden;
        max-height:0;
        background-color: #505050;
        transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    }
    header nav ul.open{
        max-height: 10000px;
    }
}
```

You can't put transitions in height property. Try this. Exaggerating the max-height doesn't affect the performace of the application.

Comment: I also have the same problem and your answer does make a difference,but the problem is  that there is a delay toease in. I tried changing the duration of ease in and out but doesnt work with this code :transition: all 0.6s ease-out;
        transition: all 0.3s ease-in;

Comment: @EltonSousa https://jsfiddle.net/s9ze8pku/ sample I created. Look at it. It should work.

Comment: Yes, it does work but still the same. It takes a bit longer to ease in than it does easing out. Is there no way it can be exactly the same?

Comment: @Ragmah As far as I know, it should be same because it has the same duration value. I don't know what's wrong with your project. Maybe post your project so I can help you.

Answer (score 0):

**Tested and Working**

Add this to your `CSS` to the `header nav ul`

```
transition: height 0.3s linear 0s;
```

[@Elton Sousa.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6340274/elton-sousa) Thanks I forgot. You have to give a specific height

```
header nav ul.open{
    height:200px;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps am not doing it the right way because I just tested and it doesn't really work on mine.

Answer (score 0):

`height` doesnt react on `transition`.. However, `opacity` does

```
.........
@media only screen ............{
    .......
    header nav ul{
        .......
        transition: all 1s;
        opacity:0;
    }
    header nav ul.open{
        .........
        opacity:1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".

Answer (score 0):

you can use slideToggle method instead of toggleClass, I have  edited code here please check
[see example here](https://jsfiddle.net/xxy4kyxb/)

```
(function ($){
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $(".burguer-nav").on("click", function(){
      $("header nav ul").slideToggle("slow");
   });
```

});
})